# Java import with wildcard does not work while import without wildcard works

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, package

I met a trouble in my study about Java package.

### environment

- Java8 1.8.9_162
- Windows7

### directories

I tried to create hoge.fuga package (just for studying Java) and placed files in directories like below.

```
+ src/
    - senario.java //import hoge.fuga.*
    - senario.class
    - Foo.java //package hoge.fuga
    - Bar.java //package hoge.fuga
    + hoge/
        + fuga/
            - Foo.class
            - Bar.class
```

### When I compile Senario.java

#### case: I import with `import hoge.fuga.*;`

compile error.

```
bad source file: .\Foo.java 
file does not contain class Foo
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the source path.
```

In this case, if I remove Foo.java and Bar.java from src/, source file is compiled without errors.

#### case: I import with `import hoge.fuga.Foo; import hoge.fuga.Bar;`

Source file is compiled without errors.

### I wonder why behavior of the compiler is different when I use wildcard?

It seems to me, only when I import with wildcard, compiler checks the source code in the src/ directory.

Is this related to java setting such as classpath or sth?

I imaginle this is rare case, but I just would like to know why this happens only when I use wildcard.

Comment: Do you have `public class Foo` in `Foo.java`?

Answer (score 0):

```
file does not contain class Foo
```

This error means the class contained by your Foo.java file does not have the right name. In Java, you should name your file by the name of the public class defined in. The file Foo.java should declare :

```
public class Foo {
}
```

Be careful with your filenames, 'senario.java' is wrong naming. You should start your class name with a capital letter (and the file with the same exact case). Here a Scenario.java may be better.

Also when you declare a package for your class, ensure you the corresponding folder hierarchy exists. In your case a class with a hoge.fuga package should be in /src/hoge/fuga folder.

Also you should configure your project. It seems your build and sources directories are mingled.

A better (and standard) file hierarchy would be

```
+ src/main/
    - Scenario.java
    + hoge/
        + fuga/
            - Foo.java
            - Bar.java
+ /target
    - Scenario.class
    + hoge/
        + fuga/
            - Foo.class
            - Bar.class
```

To configure your target directory, you have to change your project settings in your IDE.

Comment: *File Foo.java cannot declare a Bar class*: this is not categorically correct. You can have `Bar.class` declared in `Foo.java` alongside `Foo.class`

Comment: I did not want to talk about inner classes here. The problem seems linked to very basic knowledge of Java and I did not want to give a huge response with all features the language provides.

Comment: I get that. But still, you can have multiple classes in a single file, as long as there's one public class after which the file is named. In that, your statement is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and advices.  Now I understand my placement of directories are not good enough and .java source files should be separated from .class files.

But still, I wonder why "only when I use wildcard" this error is suggested and not when I use specific class import.  Are there any reason for this?  Or is this "strange behavior" of Java compiler and I should take it as is?

Answer (score 0):

Your .java files should be moved to the directory of their declared packages, and I highly recommend splitting your source files and compiled files into two different directories to avoid classpath issues.

For example, if your expected fully-qualified class name (FQCN) is `hoge.fuga.Foo` and your compile root is `src/`, then your .java file should be `src/hoge/fuga/Foo.java`, not `src/Foo.java`.

You also are storing your .class files in `src/`, which is also a bad idea. Set up the compiler to put class files in a separate directory alongside `src/`, e.g. `build/`:

```
+ my-project/
    + src/
        - senario.java //import hoge.fuga.*
        + hoge/
            + fuga/
                - Foo.java //package hoge.fuga
                - Bar.java //package hoge.fuga
    + build/
        - senario.class
        + hoge/
            + fuga/
                - Foo.class
                - Bar.class
```

This will stabilize your build and will likely resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and advices.  Now I understand my placement of directories are not good enough and .java source files should be separated from .class files.
  
But still, I wonder why "only when I use wildcard" this error is suggested and not when I use specific class import.  Are there any reason for this?  Or is this "strange behavior" of Java compiler and I should take it as is?

Comment: Probably just the compiler. I'm sure it's an operation order kind of issue. It sees the import for `hoge.fuga.Foo` and knows that one of its .java files maps to that, and so it waits to bind and test for errors, but the wildcard import code will try to find all the references it can early on by classpath-scanning. If your Foo.class file is on the classpath at compilation time, then it might scan that class file early and break, e.g. if it's already been truncated to zero length in preparation of compiling Foo.java.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I'm glad to know this compiler operation thanks to your explanation.  Now I understand what's going on.